# Extending model attributes in ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ArrayController `ActivitiesController` that lists a set of Activities. The model `Activity` defines all the long-running state but I'd like to keep in-browser state in the controller. Specifically when displaying an activity I'd like to have a toggle switch `showDetails` that indicates whether or not to give a summary or detail view to each activity.

Doing this with a computed property is easy enough. For instance this works:

```
duration: function() {
  if (!this.get('start_time') || !this.get('end_time')) { return false; }
  return moment(
  this.get('end_time'),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
      .diff(moment(this.get('start_time'),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),"minutes");
}.property('start_time', 'end_time')
```

But what I'm wondering is how do I just add a simple attribute such as:

```
showDetails : false // where "false" is just the initialised state of course
```

This seems to attach this attribute across all array elements rather than on a per attribute basis. Sorry if this is a really basic question but my head is tired from hitting it against a wall.

Comment: if I get you right, you want to have a `showDetails` attribute on each model `Activity`?

Comment: @intuitivepixel yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use an `itemController` on your `ActivitiesController`. In its simplest form, like:

```
App.ActivitiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'activity'
});
```

with the `ActivityController` being

```
App.ActivityController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    showDetails: false
});
```

so all your models in `ActivitiesController` will be *wrapped* with an `ActivityController` where you can have *'non persistent'* property like `showDetails` or anything you want for that matter.